# Ionic 3 - ios 11 - always ask for GPS location

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

For the latest ios version on the iPhone, I'm not getting the 'always' for always track your location on the iPhone. I'm getting while on the app and never. However this functionality seems to be working fine for every version previous. Any other suggestions than what I've done in XCode below would be great.

CDVLocation.m

```
if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        } else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
            [self.locationManager  requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"[Warning] No NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key is defined in the Info.plist file.");
        }
```

in the plist file

```
 <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off.</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has the logic inverted, it should be this:

```
if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
    [self.locationManager  requestAlwaysAuthorization];
} else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
} else {
    NSLog(@"[Warning] No NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key is defined in the Info.plist file.");
}
```

Notice I switched these two lines:

```
[self.locationManager  requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

You can refer to the master [source code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/src/ios/CDVLocation.m#L123).

Additionally, for iOS 11, when [requesting always permission](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization) you should include the `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your info plist.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>When always is requested in iOS 11</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>When "when in use" is requested in iOS 11</string>
```

> You are required to include the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in your app's Info.plist file. (If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key is also required.) If those keys are not present, authorization requests fail immediately.

Comment: With this update - it still does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm I updated my answer, for more information, see the video linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46847825/5099014)

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate it!